# Is there a way to edit with google docs, email attachments on Google Inbox?

Tags: gmail, google-inbox

In the new Google Inbox i haven't seen an option, when i receive document as attachments, that allows me to edit with google docs

In GMAIL, there's this:

[image]

In INBOX, I don't see any of these options

[image]

Does anyone know if this feature is there on INBOX, is it setting i have to enable, or its not yet on INBOX?